# Нейронная сеть

Tags: нейронные-сети

Может быть кто-нибудь знает хороший источник с информацией на эту тему?
(желательнее чтобы информация была попроще и с примерами)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Нейронные сети](http://www.statsoft.ru/home/textbook/modules/stneunet.html) (statsoft)
- [Нейронные сети](http://www.basegroup.ru/library/analysis/neural/) (basegroup)
- [Введение в теорию](http://www.orc.ru/~stasson/neurox.html#links) (каталог ресурсов)

Answer (score 1):

вот [здесь](http://neurones.ru/articles-1.html) есть подборка достаточно свежих статей с практическим применением. А вам какие примеры нужно? Типа участков кода? или описание практических алгоритмов?